# Showing related lookup information from several tables in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql

I'm sure this has been answered before but I couldn't find anything that matched my requirements.
I'm from an MS Access background and TSQL is what I'm slowly getting into. I'm designing a report that requires information from several different tables. There is a principal table that has the header information and there are related tables that have the MANY information. I'd like to combine the MANY information into a single view/stored procedure where the MANY information has been enumerated and listed one under the other. In MS Access I can do this using a function but thought there might be a neater way of doing this with TSQL.

Lets say the principal table is project information and one of the related tables are names of contacts working on a project. I'd like to show a view that combines the information as per the following. The contacts are individual records but in the view/sp they are combined as one field with line breaks.

```
Proj_ID    Project_Name      Project_Contacts
123        Proj ABC          Contact 1
                             Contact 2
                             Contact 3
                             Contact 4
```

I'd like to do this with several related tables.
What is the best approach and come someone give me a snippet of code to get started with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see if this works for you.

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (Proj_ID INT, Project_Name VARCHAR(10),Project_Contacts VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @TestTable VALUES
('123','Proj ABC','Contact 1'),
('123','Proj ABC','Contact 2'),
('123','Proj ABC','Contact 3'),
('123','Proj ABC','Contact 4'),
('123','Proj ABC','Contact 5'),
('124','Proj BCD','Contact 3'),
('124','Proj BCD','Contact 5'),
('125','Proj CDE','Contact 1'),
('125','Proj CDE','Contact 3'),
('125','Proj CDE','Contact 5'),
('125','Proj CDE','Contact 6'),
('125','Proj CDE','Contact 7')


SELECT Proj_ID,
      Project_Name,
      REPLACE((SELECT Project_Contacts + ','
            FROM @TestTable AS t2
            WHERE t1.Proj_ID = t2.Proj_ID
            FOR XML PATH('')),',','<BR>') AS Project_Contacts
FROM @TestTable AS t1
GROUP BY Proj_ID, Project_Name
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering Gouri, this did it perfectly, I changed the '<BR>' for CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) because it is a windows app not a web app report.

Comment: Hi Gouri just a quick follow up seeing as I'm not using this for a web app can I get away with out using FOR XML PATH. Do I replace that with something else or can I remove it completely? Thanks again!

Comment: Depends on what you want as an output, the FOR XML converts the multiple Project_Contacts for each Proj_ID, Project_Name combination into a CSV. Removing it would give you recurrences of each Project_Contacts as a line item in your result set. If you would want to jst remove the <BR> from the result set then pleased remove REPLACE( and ,',','<BR>') from the query.

Comment: Top man Gouri, thank you for responding with great answers. Sometimes that might be another way of displaying the data. On another related matter how can I strip off the final <BR>. I'm finding that the final <BR> with no text under it creates a vertical space in the rendered report. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've worked out that it can be done using a combination of Left and Len and it works but it makes the script extremely verbose...

Comment: That could become a bit too heavy, TRY THIS.
REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT Project_Contacts + ','
            FROM @TestTable AS t2
            WHERE t1.Proj_ID = t2.Proj_ID
            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''),',','<BR>') AS Project_Contacts

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question that I interpreted, SQL keywords to research ..

SELECT

INNER JOIN

GROUP BY

Below example code is what I interpreted as what you are looking for ..

```
    declare @t1 table (Project_id int, Project_Name varchar(20))
declare @t2 table (Project_id int, Project_Contacts varchar(20))

insert into @t1 (Project_id, Project_Name)
values
(1, 'ABC')
, (2, 'CDE')
, (3, 'FGH')
, (4, 'IJK')

insert into @t2 (Project_id, Project_Contacts)
values
(1, 'Contact aaa1')
, (1, 'Contact aaa1')
, (2, 'Contact bbb2')
, (3, 'Contact ccc3')
, (4, 'Contact ddd4')
, (4, 'Contact ddd4')

select table1.Project_id, table1.Project_Name, table2.Project_Contacts
from @t1 table1
    inner join
    @t2 table2
    on table1.Project_id = table2.Project_id
group by table1.Project_id, table1.Project_Name, table2.Project_Contacts
```